# How to extract image URL from the <script> in the html code in R?

Tags: r, rvest

I use rvest to extract information from the link.
But this time there is no image URL in the html_attr("src") under the respective html node.

The source code is:

```
<img alt="product name " class="cz-img large_img image_size img_slider_1060571227 img_2" id="d3-view_2" itemprop="image" style="height: auto;" src="">
          <script>
            var image_url = "https://images.xyz.com/i/314183/large/swatch-image20160708-13472-dh956c.jpg?1467959305";
            $('.img_2').attr('src',image_url);
            $('.img_2').on('load', function(){
              $('.image_message_color').show();
            });
          </script>
```

I usually use:

```
    #Get image_url
image_url<-link %>% 
  html_nodes("#d3-view_1") %>% 
  html_attr("src")
image_url
```

But here, the `src` is empty.
There are 3 or 4 images this way, and what I want to extract images.xyz.com/i/314183/large/swatch-image20160708-13472-dh956c.jpg?1467959305

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide the source url from you're extracting?

Comment: That link doesn't work for me

Comment: So it seems that value is dynamically set by JavaScript, why do you expect the non empty value?

Comment: I suggest using Regular Expressions for this propose `http:\\/\\/images.xyz.com.+.[jpg|gif|png]`

Comment: @Hack-R "this" has https://images.xyz.com/i/314183/large/swatch-image20160708-13472-dh956c.jpg?1467959305

Comment: @Bulat i know it will give an empty value that is why i asked for help that how to get that link using rvest. actually there are 3 images for that product which zooms in when we hover mouse on it.

Comment: @amrrs i cannot share the link :( . Please help. or tell me if you want to see anything in that link?

Comment: @Amin Can you tell in a bit detail?

Comment: for dynamic content you can use RSelenium which will load the page in the browser. this way you can parse the page post rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. For me it worked when I added a `html_nodes("img")` before the `html_attr("src")`:

```
library(rvest)

html <- read_html("webpage url")

html %>%
  html_nodes("tr+ tr th") %>% # adjust to your path
  html_nodes("img") %>%
  html_attr("src")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using regular expressions to extract images, here is a sample:

```
html <- readLines("webpage link")
images <- regmatches(html,regexpr("https://images.xyz.com.+.[jpg|gif|png]",html))
```

based on your scenario you can edit the RegEx.